# The "live" 3D webpage showing LRO's activity is down, is this temporary?

Tags: nasa, lro

In my [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/18966/12102) to the question "Mapping the moon: how to use the Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter (LRO) image data?" I include a link to https://lrostk.gsfc.nasa.gov/preview.cgi which is a "real-time" viewer of LRO's position and what it is currently imaging. For example, it generates screens like that shown below.

But a few hours ago a [comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEaEl.png) there pointed out that the site seems to be down. That link returns the message:

```
File '/stream.mjpgpreview.cgi' not found
```

and https://lrostk.gsfc.nasa.gov/ returns

```
The server is too busy to serve your request at this time.

The bandwidth being served (including your stream) is 1000800kbit/sec, and this exceeds the limit of 1000000kbit/sec.
```

The main "lunar" Goddard Spaceflight Center resources page is still fine though: https://lunar.gsfc.nasa.gov/resources.html

Is this unavailability a temporary condition?

The *Where Is LRO* page http://lroc.sese.asu.edu/about/whereislro is still active and generates the following map (click for full size):

[image]

---

Historical screenshot of https://lrostk.gsfc.nasa.gov/preview.cgi from [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/18966/12102):

[image]

Comment: https://lrostk.gsfc.nasa.gov/ is now showing a image (you can copy and paste it) which is updated roughly once a second, but https://lrostk.gsfc.nasa.gov/preview.cgi is still down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sent an email which started a chain (Jennifer Brill, John Keller, Emmanuel Dziwornooh). At some point during that, https://lrostk.gsfc.nasa.gov/ came back up. John Keller acknowledged that the site has intermittent problems and asked the sysadmins to ensure it stays up more reliably.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it and posting the update! Of course the primary objective is maintaining the spacecraft, research, and data integrity and the cool web page is secondary. I admire how NASA is able to do amazing science and technology hundreds of millions of miles away and still can bring it home to us at the same time.